# .api file with Google Cloud Endpoints - how do I customise

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm a little confused about the .api file which gets created when using Google Cloud endpoints.  This seems to list all methods and parameters.  It gets auto generated using the Google Plugin for Eclipse or when running endpoints.sh.  The .api file seems to be needed, otherwise a 404 is returned when accessing the API.

If I generate the endpoint class from an @Entity class it creates the .api file AND the Endpoint.java file.  My question is if I want to create a custom Endpoint.java file e.g. different parameters, then how do I do this ?  Am I supposed to update my code then manually modify the .api file, or is there a way to generate just the .api file.

Or is Google App Engine saying you can generate the Endpoint with its basic methods and that's all that is possible...?  I would have thought that the .api file should be generated based on registered endpoints in web.xml at deployment time or better still just scan for @Api annotations at deployment time and build the necessary config then.

Also if you're not using the plugin in Eclipse (e.g. you're using Maven) some further manual steps are required e.g. updating web.xml.  This is documented in the "Generating Client Libraries" section of the App Engine website - but this is surely doing more than generating a client library, it's creating the necessary deployment config server side too.  I found this confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google added support for Endpoint generation in version 1.7.7 of the appengine-maven-plugin.  This means Endpoints can now be created without use of the Eclipse plugin.  See the [original issue ticket](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/detail?id=19&can=1).

I have subsequently [blogged](http://www.planetjones.co.uk/blog/19-05-2013/google-app-engine-endpoints-with-java-maven-part1.html) about using the Maven Plugin to generate and deploy endpoints, which may be useful for getting started.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your custom endpoints. You only have to add the annotations as said in the [**documentation**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations).

I had trouble doing this, and I relised you must follow a couple of rules, namely:

- Your api and method names can't use "_", so **@Api(name="my_api")** is wrong and **@Api(name="myApi")** is right.
- Your api methods mustn't return simple types, so return a **String** is wrong, but return **MyString** is right. Your method can also return **void**.

An example of a custom endpoint should look like this:

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;

@Api(name="myApi",
     path="my_api")
public class MyEndpoint {

    @ApiMethod (name="myMethod", 
                path="my_method",
                method="httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST")
    public MyCustomObject myMethod () {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that all the annotation attributes are optional.

Then, you only have to generate the cloud endpoint libraries from [**Eclipse plugin**](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-overview) by:

```
Right click on the project -> Google -> Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Libraries
```

Your web.xml is automatically updated with:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>services</param-name>
    <param-value>mypackage.MyEndpoint</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

To be honest I don't know to do it without the plugin...

Comment: Thanks @MikO - I see when a create a custom EndPoint class the .api file is created automatically inside Eclipse. But I am using Intellij and just the GAE Maven Plugin.  Maybe I am doing something wrong with the .sh file - I will experiment.

Comment: NOTE: I only see the endpoints.sh file inside the Eclipse plugins folder (I also have Eclipse installed).

Comment: You're welcome @planetjones. As for the .api file, I'm sorry I don't understand your question very well. This file is generated the first time and updated each time you modify the class and run the generation. I'm afraid I don't know how it works out of eclipse...